# VueJs and vue-i18n error

Tags: javascript, internationalization, vue.js

im using the Webpack CLI Template.

Then i install https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ with npm install --save vue-i18n

In my main.js i do the import and set the "en" locale

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(VueI18n)
Vue.locale('en', {})

new Vue({
  el: '.nwt-mm-app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

The console output always says

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue___default.a.locale is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:802), <anonymous>:16:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:802)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
    at fn (app.js:84)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1176)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
    at app.js:709
    at app.js:712
```

Am i missing somewhat ?
Greetings,

Markus

Comment: Do you have vue-i18n installed? Check if its in your package.json or node_modules folder.

Comment: Hi ... Yes it is installed as i say with npm Install --dev vue-i18n

Answer (score 5):

Well, You can check the author's another repo.

https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n-alpha-repro

In the demo, the `vue-i18n` is like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(VueI18n)
const i18n = new VueI18n({
   locale: 'ja',
   messages: {
     ja: {
       hello: 'こんにちは'
     },
     en: {
       hello: 'hello'
     }
    }
   })

 Vue.config.productionTip = false

 /* eslint-disable no-new */
 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   i18n,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
 })
```

And it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'


Vue.use(VueI18n)

// console.log(navigator.language);
let defaultLang = "zh"

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: defaultLang,//默认语言
  messages: {
    zh:{
      hello:'你好',
      footTitle:['现货交易','采购供应','行情资讯','个人中心']
    },
    en: {
      hello: 'hello',
      footTitle:['Spot Trading','Purchase & Supply','Market Information','Personal Center']
    },
  }
})

export default i18n
```